# Using Future.add call back to retrieve data from Azure mobile service into android applicaton

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to retrieve from a Azure Mobile service to the android application, I have been using Mobile Service client to do so. Here is my code.

```
try {
            mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "URL", "Key",
                    this);

            ListenableFuture<MyObject> result =  mClient.invokeApi("CCOOutageHistoryData", "GET", null, MyObject.class);
            Futures.addCallback(result, new FutureCallback<MyObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable exc) {
                    //createAndShowDialog((Exception) exc, "Error");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(MyObject result) {
                   String Incdenti= result.getCount();
                    //createAndShowDialog(result.getCount() + " item(s) marked as complete.", "Completed Items");
                    //refreshItemsFromTable();
                }
            });
```

However, I don't get any error but , when checking using a breakpoint it does not reach the onSuccess or Onfailure methods within Future.addcallback.
I am trying to retrieve the JSON data after invoking the azure mobile service api . Please help

Comment: Are you sure the request is answered?

Comment: Hi Nadir , sorry if this is lame , but how do I check that

Comment: I don't get any errors or exceptions when I am invoking the api though

Comment: I am not sure how does the json data returned from the api is deserialised to MyObject in the above case . can some one help me understand that

Comment: I have been inspecting the azure sdk source code, and, if your custom object is not an array, they just cast the result to your class, which might be the problem. Try using a String array and check what happen

Comment: @Nadir I have declared the class MyObject with a string array, however I dint understand how can I pass string array directly instead of class

Comment: I posted a code snippet in the answers. Try with that and lets see

Comment: i am also facing a same kind of problem and as i researched Futures.addCallback(result, new FutureCallback<MyObject>() this part of the code has been depricated and the solution is to give an executor in the code ..

Answer (score 0):

Try with String[]

```
try {
            mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "URL", "Key",
                    this);

            ListenableFuture<String[]> result =  mClient.invokeApi("CCOOutageHistoryData", "GET", null, (new String[0]).getClass());
            Futures.addCallback(result, new FutureCallback<String[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable exc) {
                    //createAndShowDialog((Exception) exc, "Error");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String[] result) {
                 }
            });
```

Comment: I get tis error :  Error:(143, 67) error: incompatible types
required: ListenableFuture<String[]>
found:    ListenableFuture<CAP#1>
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends String[] from capture of ? extends String[]

Answer (score 0):

There are some samples below that may help you learning the Coutom API for Android with the .NET backend of mobile service.

1. A test sample for the Custom API in Android, please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/blob/master/e2etest/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/zumoe2etestapp/tests/CustomApiTests.java
2. The sample for the .NET backend of mobile service, please see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-quickstart.

Hope it helps. Best Regards。